# Php SQL syntax error

Tags: php

Whats wrong in following query???
am getting error

**Parse error:**

> syntax error, unexpected 'INSERT' (T_STRING)

```
$NEW_TOKEN = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `iPhone_users` (`DEVICE_TOKEN`,`NAME`,`LOGIN_ID`,`CREATED_AT`) VALUES ('$DEVICE_TOKEN','$STUDENT_FIRST_NAME','$LOGIN_ID','$TODAY')");
```

Comment: You've not closed a `"` earlier at a guess.

Comment: Switch to "mysqli" and use parameterized queries.

Comment: Please avoid posting such lame questions. There's a site called "Google". Use it to search and fix such minor issues.

Comment: Am not as smart as you mr object manipulator... Thanks for suggesting me new site called Google... I didn't know that... And Thanks @jon.. You saved my time...

Answer (score 2):

You need to close either a single quote or double quote which started before the line you pasted. There is nothing wrong with the query itself.

The error you are getting is a PHP parse error.